# me I get the error ORA-00904: : invalid identifier (im a new in sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Factura
(
FacturaID smallint not null,
FacturaFecha date,  
FacturaObservacion varchar(1000),  
constraint pkFactura primary key (FacturaID),  
constraint fkFactura foreign key (LocalID) references Cliente(ClienteID),  
constraint fkFactura foreign key (VendedorID) references Vendedor(VendedorID),  
constraint fkFactura foreign key (ClienteID) references Local1(LocalID),
);


create table Local1
(  
LocalID smallint not null, 
LocalNombre varchar(100),  
constraint pkLocal1 primary key (LocalID)
);


create table Vendedor
(  
VendedorID smallint not null,  
VendedorNombres varchar(40), 
 VendedorApellidos varchar(40),  
constraint pkVendedor primary key (VendedorID)
);

create table Cliente
(  
ClienteID smallint not null,  
ClienteDireccion varchar(40) not null,  
ClienteCiudad varchar(30) not null,  
constraint pkCliente primary key (ClienteID)
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "new SQL"? Did you see somewhere a new version of the SQL language? In your body, you just posted several CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements; does one of them throw the error you saw? And if so, which one?

Comment: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier  it gives me that error.

Comment: with "new in sql" I mean I'm learning :)

Comment: on which table is the error?

Comment: when I press run in oracle live when selecting all the first part where the table of "factura" is created

Comment: You SQL code is not valid in Oracle. Are you sure you want to use Oracle, or is it MySQL?

Comment: 1. You cannot have the same name for different constraints. 2. You cannot reference the table that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you probably got your code from another database such as MySQL, SQL Server, or DB2.

Oracle doesn't have the `SMALLINT` data type (that I replaced with `NUMBER(6)`), and discourages the use of the `VARCHAR` data type (that I replaced by `VARCHAR2`). You also forgot to add a few columns.

I modified your SQL statements and now they run in Oracle. See below:

```
create table Local1
(  
LocalID number(6) not null, 
LocalNombre varchar2(100),  
constraint pkLocal1 primary key (LocalID)
);


create table Vendedor
(  
VendedorID number(6) not null,  
VendedorNombres varchar2(40), 
 VendedorApellidos varchar2(40),  
constraint pkVendedor primary key (VendedorID)
);

create table Cliente
(  
ClienteID number(6) not null,  
ClienteDireccion varchar2(40) not null,  
ClienteCiudad varchar2(30) not null,  
constraint pkCliente primary key (ClienteID)
);

create table Factura
(
FacturaID number(6) not null,
FacturaFecha date,  
FacturaObservacion varchar2(1000),
LocalID number(6),
VendedorID number(6),
ClienteID number(6),
constraint pkFactura primary key (FacturaID),  
constraint fkFactura1 foreign key (LocalID) references Cliente(ClienteID),  
constraint fkFactura2 foreign key (VendedorID) references Vendedor(VendedorID),  
constraint fkFactura3 foreign key (ClienteID) references Local1(LocalID)
);
```

See them running at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64782).